# Access, How can I change lowercase letter of first letter in last name to uppercase

Tags: forms, ms-access, replace, ms-access-2007

I would like to change lowercase letter of first letter in last name to uppercase by using code

my code from form is :

Option Compare Database

Private Sub Text19_Click()

Text19 = UCase(Text19)

End Sub

but there is no change to my table!

Furthermore, how can I find last name with a space, comma or period and make it without a space, comma and period.

such as

Moon,

Moon.

[space] Moon

change them to just

Moon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no change to your table, maybe your field is not bound to the recordset? Maybe you need to 'Refresh' your form.

Also, it looks like you are trying to use this code on a TextBox? 
Code would be as follows:

```
Private Sub Text19_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Text19 = Trim(Text19) ' Get rid of leading and trailing spaces.
If right(Text19, 1) = "." Or right(Text19, 1) = "," Then ' Remove comma, period
    Text19 = left(Text19, Len(Text19) - 1)
End If
Text19 = UCase(left(Text19, 1)) & Mid(Text19, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but Im really sorry but can you please tell me where to put those codes?? what I did was make a form from the table and set the data as LastName column and go to event  -> on click -> code builder and copy + paste that? no it is using in my workplace but I am really new to msaccess thank you

Comment: You said you already have a form with a small amount of code, but it doesn't work correctly (doesn't change the table). Is your form showing multiple records at a time, or only one? I assume you can scroll to see other records? First, change the value in your text field manually, then scroll to another record and select it. Now scroll back to the record you just changed. Does it reflect the change? If not, your form is not setup correctly. If changed, then paste the above code in your 'Private Sub Text19_Click()' and delete your line Text19 = UCase(Text19). BTW, I would use dblClick instead!

Comment: I deleted all other records and have only one code which you just wrote, and after I save that code and get back to my table, it doesn't change the table even though I clicked refresh all buttons ,,my control source in Data shows LastName correctly,, is there any button that I have to run the code as like other programs? I just clicked save button sorry about that and thx for the quick reply

Comment: What happens if you simply open the form, then make a change to the field, then attempt to go to a new record? Does your change get saved? If not, you have the field properties incorrect. Also, look at the 'Event' properties of the text field and make sure you have 'Event Procedure' for the 'On Click' property. If not, and the control is named 'Text19', just add the link to the code.

Comment: when I add some new last names in the form, they go to new records in the 'name' column, and I have 'Event Procedure' for the 'On Click' property and I don't get that to chehck the control is named 'Text19', I just cannot find the 'control'. I just copied and pasted the above code to my database and save it, and there is no change to my table, here is my code :

Comment: Option Compare Database

Private Sub Text19_Click()

Text19 = Trim(Text19)   ' Get rid of leading and trailing spaces.
If Right(Text19, 1) = "." Or Right(Text19, 1) = "," Then   ' Remove comma, period
    Text19 = Left(Text19, Len(Text19) - 1)
End If
Text19 = UCase(Left(Text19, 1)) & Mid(Text19, 2)

End Sub

Comment: is that a problem that I am using textbox??

Comment: No, I just tested. The issue is you need to use the double-click event instead of the click-event. I updated the code above, so give that a try. A double-click in the textbox will make the changes you need.

Comment: Im really sorry, so to make a change, do you save the database and return access and click the table you have? to check the changes have been applied? because there is no change to my table which has list of last names,,, I'm very sorry for interrupting you

Comment: (1) Does your form have 'record selectors' at the bottom of your form? If so, you should be able to scroll thru records in your table (if you only have one record, add some more records!). Using your form, change the value in the field, then scroll away, then back to that record. (2) Did the change get recorded? If not, your form setup is to blame. Please answer both questions.

Comment: no.. there is no record selector.. I will figure it out how to make record selector..

Comment: Im sorry but do you mean the record navigation in the 'button' ?

Comment: Also, try adding the following line of code just after your line: Private Sub Text19_DblClick(Cancel As Integer) 
MsgBox "Value: " & Me.Text19 & vbCrLf & "Control Source: " & Me.Text19.ControlSource & vbCrLf & "Locked: " & Me.Text19.Locked

This should display some info when you Double-Click on that textbox. If no message, your event is not being executed. If you get the message, make sure 'Control Source' shows the  'LastName' field in your table.